# Escaping &quot; in Rails and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have an array of hashes that consists of my product data in @product_records. I can extract the name of the product using the map function like this:

```
<%= @product_records.map{|x|x["Name"]} %>
```

which renders exactly how I want it to the page like this:

```
["Product1","Product2",...,"Productn"]
```

I want to try and pass this into a javascript variable so that I can use it with JQuery autocomplete.

```
var data = <%= @product_records.map{|x|x["Name"]} %>
```

When I try and set it though the double quotes are escaping like this:

```
[&quot;Product1&quot;, &quot;Product2&quot;,...,&quot;Productn&quot;]
```

I have tried various things to try and get the quotes back (.to_json etc) but nothing seems to work. There probably a very simple answer to this but I can't find what it is.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `<%= raw your_variable %>` :)

Comment: cheers. I knew it would be simple (perhaps not as simple as 3 letters though). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: raw is the single most helpful thing I've read in the past few days of being stuck on this. thanks @svilen

Comment: Damn! I was one hour around replacing the js var... Until I started to think that had to be an easier way to do this. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Make sure this variable is not settable by the end user...otherwise, you will open yourself up to xss attacks - use raw with caution

Comment: o god thank you so much, saved me from so much headache

Comment: Saved. I kept trying to use 'raw' in the controller where I was creating an array, but it didn't work until I tried 'raw' in the actual js code were it used my array. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

When you use that variable in javascript make sure, you have single quote to execute rails code in javascript.

```
'<%= raw @products.to_json %>'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use like this, for example: `<%= j raw @products %>`